# Asymptotic conditional distribution of $\bar{Y}\mid\bar{X}=x$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, asymptotics, hypothesis-testing

I'm reviewing for my qualifying exam and I'm stuck on part of a problem.

**Setup**

Suppose that $(X,Y)$ are two random variables with joint distribution
$
\begin{equation}
f(x,y\mid\alpha,\beta)=c(\alpha,\beta)\exp(-\alpha x-\beta y)\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{x^j y^j}{j!^2}
\end{equation}
$
for $x,y>0$ and $c(\alpha,\beta)=\alpha\beta-1$.

Let $(X_1,Y_1)...(X_n,Y_n)$ be a random sample from $(X,Y)$.

**Problem**

Derive the asymptotic distribution of $\bar{Y}\mid\bar{X}=\bar{x}$.

**Attempt/Thoughts**

The joint distribution of $(X_i,Y_i)_{i\leq n}$ is given by:
$$
f((x_i,y_i)_n\mid\alpha,\beta)=c(\alpha,\beta)^n \exp\left(-\alpha \sum_i x_i-\beta \sum_i y_i\right) \prod^n_{i=1} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{x_i^j y_i^j}{j!^2}
$$

The joint distribution above is a 2-parameter exponential family (likely not full rank since we must have $\alpha\beta>1$, so there is no open rectangle on $\mathbb{R}^2$). Because it's an exponential family, the conditional distribution $(\sum_i y_i\mid \sum_i x_i=s)\iff (\bar{Y}\mid\bar{X}=\bar{x})$ will be a one-parameter exponential family, free of $\alpha$. However, I'm not sure how to derive this explicitly, let alone obtain its asymptotic distribution. If I follow Bayes' rule, then I have to compute somehow a marginal distribution of $\bar{X}$, in the presence of the pesky $\sum x^j y^j$ term.

Does anyone have any hints on how to get started? Thank you!

**Edit**

I believe I have a solution. Here is a rough outline for now. I can post the complete solution later.

Using multivariate CLT, we can compute the asymptotic distribution of $\bar{X},\bar{Y}$. The variances and covariances can be computed directly from the density. Then we use Bayes rule to compute the conditional density. This [website](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/gaussianprocess/node7.html) also helped for calculating the marginal density of $\bar{X}$.